# VBA parsing of numeric ranges from string

Tags: parsing, vba, excel

I need to parse numeric range from User Form (VBA, Excel).
For example: {1-3,5,9} -> {1,2,3,5,9,}

The question has already been discussed here:
[Advanced parsing of numeric ranges from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011657/advanced-parsing-of-numeric-ranges-from-string)

The task is quite standart, is there any ready-made solution for VBA?

Comment: Sounds like a cool problem. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'd suggest implementing the logic that your link provides in VBA...

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the encompassing braces are not part of the string.  Consider the following UDF:

```
Public Function DashFiller(sIn As String) As String
    Dim N As Long, NN As Long
    DashFiller = ""
    ary = Split(sIn, ",")
    For N = LBound(ary) To UBound(ary)
        If InStr(1, ary(N), "-") > 0 Then
            ary2 = Split(ary(N), "-")
            ary(N) = ary2(0)
            For NN = ary2(0) + 1 To ary2(1)
                ary(N) = ary(N) & "," & NN
            Next NN
        End If
    Next N
    DashFiller = Join(ary, ",")
End Function
```

So if A1 contains:
1-2,3,4,5,9-12

and B1 contains:
=DashFiller(A1)

then B1 would display:
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,12